# How to use the word 'contrary'?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, word-usage

Is it right to say

> **contrary** to our interest to reduce the size of the paper

I want to say that we want to reduce the size of the paper but we cannot do it, due to specific reasons.

Comment: Not with out an _It is_ in front

Comment: "We would like to reduce the size of the paper, but there are factors that make such a move impractical."

Comment: No, you cannot. See usage examples to better understand how to use *contrary* and to find the right word to use in your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be pedantic about it (and I at least know that, I do) you should mind the fact that 'contrary' has a precise definition in some spheres, and that (by my observations) that meaning does seem to affect the meaning of the word in ordinary language.

The word, 'contrary', refers to the idea of two mutually exclusive truths. Example: I painted my house all red. I painted my house all green. They could both be false, either one could be true, but it is impossible for them both to be true.

Note that the word 'contradictory' also has a precise and distinct meaning. It refers to the idea of two statements that can not be simultaneously true or false. Example: I painted my house all red. I did not paint my house all red. If one statement is true, then the other must be false.

That said, and given what you want to say, I advise you not to use 'contrary' at all, and to use 'counter', 'contra', or 'against' instead. May I suggest, *Contra our best interests: we can not reduce the size of the paper.*

Answer (score 0):

How about one of the following:

'Contrary to what would be our best course, we are unable to reduce the size of the paper'

'Contrary to our best interests, we are unable....'

'Contrary to our need to reduce the paper size, we are prevented from doing so by....'

Comment: None of those work, in my estimation.  Each contains a built-in contradiction to what you mean to say.  For example, suppose “Contrary to our best interests, we are unable to do X” is intended to mean that we can't do X because X is against our interests.  However, it actually means that being unable to do X is against our interests, and we would do X if we could.  On the other hand, if you actually intended the latter meaning, many people will inadvertently read it as having the former meaning.  Hence none of the examples work properly.